# What can happen when 2.3*10^28 positrons collide with 2.3*10^28 electrons?

Tags: particle-physics, electricity, electromagnetic-radiation

I'm interested in this question after a writer friend asked me what happens when a human gets bombarded with positrons. Didn't want to post this under scifi because I want more "scientific" answers...

Potassium isotope in human body produce around 4000 positrons daily. What would happen, let's say, that number is 100 billion, or infinity?

---

**EDIT**

To ask this in strictly physics terms:

What can happen when 2.3*10^28 positrons annihilate with 2.3*10^28 electrons?

I'm thinking photons get emitted and nothing else really happens.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The rest mass of an electron is 0.511 MeV. When an electron and a positron annihilate their mass turns to energy (two 0.511 MeV photons) so for each annihilation an energy of 1.022 MeV is released. One electron volt is $1.602 \times 10^{-19}$ joules, so in joules the energy released is $1.637 \times 10^{-13}$ J.

You ask what happens if $2.3 \times 10^{28}$ positrons annihilate with $2.3 \times 10^{28}$ electrons. Well, we simply multiply the energy we calculated above by $2.3 \times 10^{28}$ to find the total energy release would be $3.765 \times 10^{15}$ J.

Figures like this are hard to put in context, so to get a handle on this figure note that a 1 megaton nuclear explosion produces $4.184 \times 10^{15}$ joules. So the electron-positron annihilation would produce the same energy as a 900 kiloton nuclear bomb, which is about 60 times as powerful as the bomb dropped on Hiroshima.

Answer (score 2):

> Would the human start emitting photons and die?

EDIT: This answer is an answer to the original question regarding "a billion" positions. The question was subsequently edited to now read "2.3*10^28" positrons. That is not cool.

The human would start emitting photons.

This is exactly what happens during a PET (Positron Emission Tomography) scan at your local hospital.  Except the positron emitter is not some haywire potassium atom, but rather an injection of some radioactive isotope like 11C.  The body does emit a ton of ~511keV photons during the PET scan as a result of positron/electron annihilation. These are used to reconstruct images of the human body just like external x-rays are used to reconstruct images in, say, CT scanning.  There is a non-negligible dose of radiation due to PET scanning (just as there is for CT scanning and 2d x-ray imaging) and because of this there is a slight increase in risk of cancer.  There are papers in medical journals about this risk and the approximate numerical values for the risk increase over non-irradiated humans.

Thus, yes, the human would die--eventually, as all human must die--and maybe a little earlier on average than usual...

Comment: Actually, I'm thinking as the electrons get annihilated, more will just "flow" into the human body from the surroundings. Nothing harmful will happen to the dude. Or would he actually get electrocuted?....

Comment: Well, you changed your question. First it was a billion positrons. Now it's 2.3*10^28 positrons. It's not cool to make an edit like that...